# Android studio insert string as resource in "strings.xml"

Tags: android-studio

I want to add certains strings as resource in file "strings.xml".

For example in this picture:
[image]

I want to use ip1 and port1 as resources in "strings.xml" through java. Anyone know how to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to save or change values in strings.xml since it is a compiled resource. you can choose other ways to save datas, take a look at this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="ip">INSERT TEXT FOR IP HERE</string>
    <string name="port">INSERT TEXT FOR PORT HERE</string>
</resources>
```

onCreate() within an Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d("LOG_TAG", getString(R.string.ip));
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", getString(R.string.port));
}
```

Let me know if this answers your question.